# Como acessar a url que me retorna no console.log?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, firebase, ionic3

Estou realizando um upload de fotos para o firebase storage, tudo ocorre bem, o arquivo é transferido e gravado lá dentro. Porém quando eu me inscrevo dentro da tarefa eu não consigo obter a url do download da imagem para gravar em uma variável e enviar ao banco posteriormente.

O que está me retornando é isso no momento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha função é a seguinte:

```
  uploadFoto(){
    if(this.blobFotoPerfil){
    const ref = 
   this.afs.ref(`profissionais/${this.nomeUsuarioPastaStorage}/perfil.jpg`);
    const task = ref.put(this.blobFotoPerfil);

    this.percentualProgresso = task.percentageChanges();

    task.snapshotChanges().subscribe( data => {
    console.log(data.downloadURL);
    console.log(data.ref.getDownloadURL());
    console.log(data.ref.fullPath);
  })

 }
```

O método getDownloadURL() me retorna aquele C ali no console, e dentro dele tem a url da foto, porém eu não sei como eu faço para acessá-lo.

Comment: Tente `C.i` ou `C['i']` ou ainda `data.ref.getDownloadURL()['i']`... etc

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

  uploadFoto(){
    if(this.blobFotoPerfil){
      const ref = this.afs.ref(`profissionais/${this.nomeUsuarioPastaStorage}/perfil.jpg`);
      const task = ref.put(this.blobFotoPerfil);
  
      this.percentualProgresso = task.percentageChanges();

      task.snapshotChanges().subscribe( data => {
        data.ref.getDownloadURL().then( data => {
          this.profissional.urlFotoPerfil = data;
          console.log(this.profissional.urlFotoPerfil);
        })
      })

    }